# x86_64 Linux: plotting feature

Tags: plotting

Some features with V10.0.1.0 plotting under x86_64 Linux (xubuntu 12.04 & 14.04). I use ListPlot, but I also see this using other Plot functions.

Generate some data: `tdata = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {32, 2}];`.
Plot the first series: `ListPlot[tdata[[All, 1]], Joined -> True]` to get
[image]

Plot both series (`ListPlot[{tdata[[All, 1]], tdata[[All, 2]]}, Joined -> True]`) to get
[image]

Here's where the features start.  Specify styles using `ListPlot[{tdata[[All, 1]], tdata[[All, 2]]}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]` and see
[image]

Second series dashed (`ListPlot[{tdata[[All, 1]], tdata[[All, 2]]}, Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}]`) gives
[image]

Note the dashed Frame.

Can anybody else reproduce these effects?

Comment: I don't see it on Win7x64. However, the default for this type of plot (as far as I know) is with axes, not a frame. How did you change this default (or is this just the default, somehow, on your system but not mine)?

Comment: On OS X I do not get a frame unless I explicitly ask for one using `Frame -> True`.  Have you modified the default settings?

Comment: Indeed!  Set Frame->True, Axes->False before commencing